# Best way to manage a static property

Tags: c#, static, thread-safety

I have this code:

```
public static class ProcessClass()
{
     public static string MyProp {get;set;}

     public static void ProcessMethod(InputObject input)
     {
         if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyProp)
              MyProp = input.Name();

         //do stuff

         MyProp = null;

     }   

 }
```

Now, everything except for `MyProp` was already in place. I needed a way to track the original `input.Name` throughout the code since it can change and also because `ProcessMethod` could get called again internally with a different `input.Name` value due to business rules, and I need to state that this second calling came from `input.Name`.

Obviously, this is bad since if two people do this at the same time, they will both share the same `MyProp` value, and simply making is null at the end seems dangerous and hacky. I don't really have the option of changing this method to be non static because that would involve changing A LOT of the codebase, which isn't really an option.

What are ways around using a static property, but still being able to keep my original `input.Name` value without risking thread safety issues? One option I am thinking is is to have every method accept an `input.Name()` and track is that way(and remove the `MyProp`), but I can picture that getting out of hand fast, and extremely messy.

I don't need to have this be a property, but if it is it obviously needs to be static in this class.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this, but I'd strongly suggest making `MyProp` or whatever similar solution you end up with `private` rather than `public`. That way at least you'll eliminate the chance that it will get changed by any method outside `ProcessClass`, thereby reducing your likelihood of failure quite substantially.

Comment: Generally, it seems like it's a part of a bigger design issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since it may be a multi-user environment, then replace the string with a `ConcurrentDictionary` where you store the `input.Name()` as a `Value` and as `Key` the unique identifier of the user (an id, a name, etc).